# why I get slightly different colour even though I put the same RGB number?

Tags: ios, uicolor

[image]

In `launchScreen.StoryBoard` I set the colour manually using color picker like the picture above. as you can see red = 255, green=171, blue=0

from the launch screen, it will contiune to MainVC, in MainVC, I set the splash screen when fetching data from the internet

and because I use the library, I should put the colour programatically. I use the code below to generate the colour

```
backgroundColor: UIColor(red:255/255, green:171/255, blue:0/255, alpha:1.0)
```

I think I have put exactly the same RGB number , but the result is slightly different.

you can see from the gif file in here: http://g.recordit.co/tANf6VH4iC.gif
the colour near the logo will be different after around 2 seconds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the color scheme settings by clicking [image] button and then select `sRGB XXXXX` scheme as shown below. Now correct the `RGB` values and see the results.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Click on that settings (gear) icon and select the same coloring scheme.  That will correct this.